# How to use an array element value if the array name is extracted later (in Python)?

Tags: python

eg:

CASE 1:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print('arr1[0]')
```

Output is:

> 1

CASE 2: (in the same program, after finding out name of array)

```
new = 'arr1'

print('new[0]')
```

Output is :

> a

In case 1, we are accessing list elements but in case 2, we are accessing string elements.
The problem is that I want that the computer should understand that this is the same arr1 defined in Case 1.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: the variable `new` has `string` in it. Fix the typo in your code like this `new = arr1`

Comment: @Sachin I want the output in 2nd case to be 1 only...i.e., it should take arr1[0]

Comment: @GeekSambhu No, actually, I want to change into string first and then tell the computer that this string name is the same array defined earlier. Is there some way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(eval('arr1[0]'))

new = 'arr1'

print(eval('new[0]'))
```

The second case will, however, not give you the answer you wanted. You need to use eval twice:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(eval('arr1[0]'))

new = eval('arr1')

print(eval('new[0]'))
```

Comment: It is not working....actually, I have extracted the name of array(i.e., arr1)  later in program (i.e., in case2) and I want the computer to understand thta it is the same  arr1 defined earlier and pick its value...is there some way?

Comment: Exactly what you asked is working. The last result should be `1` and it prints `1`. What is different than you would expect?

Comment: Thanks ....It is correct approach...it is just that syntax should be eval(new)[0] ..and not eval(new[0])...that is why i wasnt able to implement on my compiler....but now it is working fine

Comment: Why would you need to do `eval(new)[0]`? new is already evaled: `new = eval('arr1')`. `eval(new)[0]` would be `eval(eval('arr1'))[0]`. That makes no sense. Maybe you forgot the quotation marks? My proposal is `eval('new[0]')` and not `eval(new[0])`...

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print('arr1[0]')

new = 'arr1'

print(eval(new)[0])
```

This will first evaluate value of the variable `new` and then get the index element.

Comment: The author wanted to evaluate a string in the second case. You changed it to a non-string.

Comment: @mhk, if the solution provided solved your problem then pls mark it correct.